# KNN and Classification Factor

Tags: r, machine-learning, supervised-learning, k-nearest-neighbour, caret

I'm studying the KNN algorithm and its application on R. If I correctly understood, KNN is a supervised algorithm able to classify an unlabeled item according to the predominant belonging class in the K data points. To apply KNN in R, using the package `caret`, I saw the following code:

```
knn(train,test,cl,k=1,l=0)
```

I read that CL is the Classification Factor. In the examples I saw, based on randomly created vectors, the classification factor was generated in this way:

```
cl <- factor(c(rep("class1",5),rep("class2",5)))
```

It seems that this function partitions the dataset, composed of 10 cases, such that the first 5 cases will belong to the class1, and the remaining 5 to the class2. But what if I want to classify the item according to the outcomes of a variable of the dataset (i.e., my "response variable"), such that each possible outcome of the variable groups my data into classes? I thought that considering a response variable, it was sufficient to assign `cl <- response` so I tried it on the classical Iris dataset of R. So I created the training set: `trainiris == iris[1:70,]`, then I used an item outside the trainset `testiris <- iris[99,]` to test on it the algorithm and I used the factor `cl <- trainiris$Speciesas` my classification factor (to predict the flower species according to the other variables): then I tried my KNN model:

```
summary(knn(trainiris,testiris,trainiris$Species,k=1, l=0))
```

But R returned this:

```
Error in knn(trainiris, testiris, trainiris$Species, k = 1, l = 0) :NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In knn(trainiris, testiris, trainiris$Species, k = 1, l = 0) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In knn(trainiris, testiris, trainiris$Species, k = 1, l = 0) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

What am I doing wrong?